# tqdm notebook: increase bar width

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, tqdm

I have a task I'd like to monitor the progress of; it's a brute force np problem running in a `while` loop.

For the first x (unknown number) iterations of the loop it discovers an unknown additional number of future combinations (many per loop), eventually it progresses through the solution to a point where it is solving puzzles (each loop is a single solution) faster than it is finding new possible puzzles and it eventually solves the last puzzle it found (100%).

I've created some fake growth to provide a repeatable example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

growthFactorA = 19
growthFactorB = 2

prog = tqdm(total=50, dynamic_ncols=True)

done = []
todo = [1]
while len(todo)>0:
    current = todo.pop(0)
    if current < growthFactorA:
        todo.extend(range(current+1, growthFactorA+growthFactorB))
    done.append(current)
    prog.total = len(todo) + len(done)
    prog.update()
```

You'll see the total eventually stops at `389814` at first it is growing much faster that the loop is solving puzzles, but at a point the system stops growing.

**It is impossible to calculate the number of iterations before running the algorithm.**

The blue bar is confined to the original total amount used at initialization. My goal is to achieve something similar to if the initial total was set to 389814, it's okay that during the growth period (early on in the trial) the progress bar appears to move backwards or not move as the total increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/883#issuecomment-575873544 for now you could do:
 `prog.container.children[0].max = prog.total` (after setting the new `prog.total`).

This is even more annoying in case of writing code to run on both notebooks and CLI (`from tqdm.auto import tqdm`), where you'll have to first check `hasattr(prog, 'container')`.